# Return promise-based callback from sequelize-method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a model that looks like this.

```
var sequelize = require('../database.js').sequelize,
    Sequelize = require('../database.js').Sequelize,

User = sequelize.define('user', {},{
    classMethods: {
        createRider: function(params) {
            var values = [],
                userAttributes = sequelize.models.userAttributes,
                user = User.build(),
                name = userAttributes.build({name: 'name', value: params.name}),
                fbprofile = userAttributes.build({name: 'fbprofile', value: params.fbprofile}),
                phone = userAttributes.build({name: 'phone', value: params.phone});

            user = user.save().then((user) => {
                sequelize.Promise.all([
                    fbprofile.save(),
                    name.save(),
                    phone.save()
                ])
                .then((attributes) => {
                    user.addUserAttributes(attributes);
                });
            });
            return user;
        }
    }
});



module.exports = User;
```

I call it like this, and wish to ouput some of the userdata:

```
app.get('/rider/create',
    (req, res) => {
        var User = sequelize.models.user,
        user = User.createRider(req.query);
        res.json(user);
    }
);
```

as user is defined in a callback promise, `.then`, it won't contain the userdata when I ouput it. How can I wait to return the data first when the callback is done?

Comment: Is `User` meant to be global?

Comment: @gcampbell no, why?

Comment: There's no `var`. (Not that it probably affects your question.)

Comment: User isn't global, there is a , on the line before. Indent is off though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your createRider method returns a promise, not a value, so you can't assign it like `user = User.createRider(req.query);`, but you have to wait for the promise to complete.

```
User.createRider(req.query).then(user => {
  res.json(user);
}
```

The user object needs to be returned at the end of the promise chain that createRider returns. Since the last expression you return is `user.addUserAttributes(attributes)`, i assume that `user.addUserAttributes(attributes)` is also a promise chain that returns the user at the end.

Comment: Not sure how you mean with end of the promise chain? If I put it inside the last "then" that's a part of a local function with in the method and it won't be returned right?

Comment: the .then() method of createRider will be called with one argument, that is the returned value from the last .then() inside createRider, which in this case is user.addUserAttributes(attributes). if addUserAttributes is also a promise chain then the argument passed to .createRider.then() will be the returned value of the last .then() inside addUserAttributes.

Comment: Yes I have this problem, not sure how to solve it though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38037533/how-to-pass-on-variables-in-promise-chain/38037689#38037689