# How to pass on variables in promise-chain?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this promise-chain. in the second promise, I need user, that is returned by user.save. How can I get it without breaking the promise-chain? I need it to be one chain because I need the last promise to return the right attribute to the promise of when the function is called.

I call a method like this:

```
User.createRider(req.query).then((user) => {
    res.json(user);
});



User = sequelize.define('user', {},{
    classMethods: {
        createRider: function(params) {
            var values = [],
                userAttributes = sequelize.models.userAttributes,
                user = User.build(),
                name = userAttributes.build({name: 'name', value: params.name}),
                fbprofile = userAttributes.build({name: 'fbprofile', value: params.fbprofile}),
                phone = userAttributes.build({name: 'phone', value: params.phone});

            user = user.save()
                    .then(sequelize.Promise.all([
                            fbprofile.save(),
                            name.save(),
                            phone.save()
                        ])
                    )
                    .then((attributes) => {
                        user.addUserAttributes(attributes);
                        return user;
                    });
            return user;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you post the code for addUserAttributes() as well please?

Comment: I'm not going to post this as an answer since you're specifically asking about Promises, but I will say that this problem is both trivial and clear to solve with async.js.  I use async.waterfall for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly what yoy need, you can try smth like this code:

```
user = user.save()
    .then(savedUser => {
        return sequelize.Promise.all([
            fbprofile.save(),
            name.save(),
            phone.save()
        ])
        .then((attributes) => {
            console.log(savedUser); // this guy

            user.addUserAttributes(attributes);
            return user;
        });
    });
```

Comment: No, this will return user from the wrong promise-chain, updated question for clarity.

Comment: Why is it _the wrong promise-chain_? The caller will still get the returned `user` from the last `then()`.

Comment: I don't see how this solution will work. savedUser is not in scope for the second promise.

Comment: @NickLong yes it is.

Comment: @Himmators the caller only cares about *when* the returned promise will get fulfilled and what it will get fullfilled *with* (here, `return user`, but it could be anything). It won't matter if it was created with some promise chain or not.

Comment: @Himmators Just throwing a wild guess here - is your intention to return the saved user through the promise? If so, just replace `return user` with `return savedUser` in this example.

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this is what you are looking for:

```
user = user.save();
let seq = user.then(sequelize.Promise.all([
    fbprofile.save(),
    name.save(),
    phone.save()
]));

return Promise.all([user,seq])
    .then((results) => result[0].addUserAttributes(results[1]));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, wether I entirely understand your code/intentions, but I think you're looking for sth. like this:

```
User = sequelize.define('user', {},{
    classMethods: {
        createRider: function(params) {
            var userAttributes = sequelize.models.userAttributes;
            var attrs = [
                {name: 'name', value: params.name},
                {name: 'fbprofile', value: params.fbprofile},
                {name: 'phone', value: params.phone},
            ];

            return sequelize.Promise.all(Array.prototype.concat(
                User.build().save(),
                attrs.map(o => userAttributes.build(o).save())
            )).then(([user, ...attributes]) => {
                user.addUserAttributes(attributes);
                return user;
            })
        }
    }
});
```